# Why perform transformations in middleware?

Tags: xslt, architecture, middleware

A remote system sends a message via middleware (MQ) to my application.

In middleware a transformation (using xslt) is applied to this message. It is just reformatted and there is no enrichment nor validation. My system is the only consumer of this transformed message and the xslt is maintained by my team.

The original author of all of this has long gone and I am wondering why he thought it was a good idea to do the transformation in middleware rather than in my app. I can't see the value in moving this to middleware, it makes it less visible and less simple to maintain.

Also I would have thought that the xslt would be maintained by the message producer not the consumer.

Are there any guidelines for this sort of architecture? Has he done the right thing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a bad idea to modify a message body in the middleware. This negatively affects the maintainability and performance.

The only reason of doing this is trying to connect two incompatible endpoints without modifying them. This would require the transformation of the source content to be understood by the destination endpoint.

The motivation to delegate middleware to perform transformation could be a political one (endpoints are maintained by different teams, management is reluctant to touch the endpoint code, etc.).

Comment: In its intent, this architectural `adapter` is very similar with the `adapter` design pattern. The problem solved is probably the same: ["An 'off the shelf' component offers compelling functionality that you would like to reuse, but its 'view of the world' is not compatible with the philosophy and architecture of the system currently being developed"](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/adapter).

Comment: I agree with your comment and I think you are right about the motive.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to create an application architecture where there is a need to serve data to different users in different formats, and perhaps receive data in different formats (think weather reports, or sports news), then creating a hub capable of doing the transformations between many different formats makes excellent sense. (Whether you call that "middleware" is up to you.) Perhaps your predecessor had this kind of architecture in mind, but it never grew big or complex enough to justify the design.

Answer (score 1):

From a architectural point of view, it's a good idea to provide consumers of messages or content that is in a humanly readable format, e.g. xslt, unless there is a significant performance gain in using a binary format.

In the humanly readable format case, one simply has to look at the message to verify that it is correct.  In the binary case, one would have to develop a utility to tranform binary message into a humanly readable form.  Different implementers of such a utility may not always interpret the binary form as intended and it may turn into a finger pointing exercise as to who or what is correct.

Also, if one is looking at what's in the queue, it is easier to make sense of it if the messages are in a humanly readable format.

It doesn't hurt to start with humanly readable format and get the app working first.  Then profile the app and see if in the big picture the transformation routines are significant sources of delay.  If yes, then go to a binary format.

It would have been preferable to have the original message producer provide messages in xslt format, but they must have had good reasons for doing what they did when they did it. E.g potentially other consumers, xslt didn't exist then, resource constraints, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Read about the ***[`adaptor`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern)*** design pattern and you will understand the intent of the current system architecture.

Comment: Thanks for this - I am already aware of the adapter pattern. While I recognise that this is the pattern applied here it does not explain why.